# Excelのセルに時間を楽に入力する方法が知りたいです。

Tags: vba, excel

日報を毎日作成するのですが、Excelのセルに実施時間を楽に入力する方法を知りたいです。
9:00～11:00のような感じで一つのセル（結合していない）に入力し、
下のセルにも同じように、11:00～12:00のように時間を入力していきます。
関数でもＶＢＡでもリストボックスでも何でも良いので、いい案があれば教えてください。

Comment: 最初のセルは２時間で次は１時間なら、その次のセルはどうしたいのですか？

Comment: これは、１例なので特に決まってないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

書き換える必要のある部分だけ抜き出すと多少楽かもしれません。
同シートに非表示列を作りたくなければ値だけコピーして清書用のシートに貼り付けるなど。

| 開始時刻(非表示セル) | 作業時間(非表示セル) | 表示列用関数 | 表示サンプル |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9（手入力） | 2（手入力） | =text(A1/24,"h:mm")&" ~ "&text(A1/24+B1/24,"h:mm") | 9:00 ~ 11:00 |
| =A1+B1（続けて作業ならこれをオートフィル） | 1（手入力） | （オートフィル） | 11:00 ~ 12:00 |
| 13.5（作業の隙間ある場合は手入力） | 1.5（手入力） | （オートフィル） | 13:30 ~ 15:00 |

Comment: ありがとうございます。
非表示列に入力できないですよね？
入力後に非表示にするという認識で良いでしょうか。

Comment: はい、入力する時はセルの再表示で表示させて入力して、見せる（提出する）時は隠しておくイメージです。